# XNA windows phone 7 how to create simple text input?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

how can i create a text box for input,  in XNA windows phone 7 development?

Answer (score 1):

There is BeginShowKeybordInput method in Guide class, which can help you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.guide_methods.aspx
But if you're targeting Mango you can create a Silverlight and XNA application. Which let's combine both frameworks.

Comment: if you want an XNA only solution, then BeginShowKeyboardInput should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Rob Miles has blogged about this here :-

http://www.robmiles.com/journal/2011/11/18/guide-text-entry-in-windows-phone.html

Hope this helps.

Paul Diston